# Why my Grid System is not working in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sass

{
I have done the coding well but may be i have something missing

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Grid Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device width  initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">8 </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">4</div>

    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't show the 8 and 4 grid  .... show them in row

Comment: 8 next to 4 = 12, So they are a row.

Comment: yeah but they are in 2 row like   .... 8 and thn in the second row there is 4

Comment: Can you provide all your code ? In your example, Bootstrap isn't linked in your head tag..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Link your bootstrap css file in the header

and make sure that you provide the valid location of the bootstrap css file in the href .